# MongoDB Community Kubernetes Operator and Custom Persistent Volumes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I'm trying to deploy a MongoDB replica set by using the MongoDB Community Kubernetes Operator in Minikube.
I followed the instructions on the official GitHub, so:

- Install the CRD
- Install the necessary roles and role-bindings
- Install the Operator Deploy the Replicaset

By default, the operator will creates three pods, each of them automatically linked to a new persistent volume claim bounded to a new persistent volume also created by the operator (so far so good).

However, I would like the data to be saved in a specific volume, mounted in a specific host path. So in order I would need to create three persistent volumes, each mounted to a specific host path, and then automatically I would want to configure the replicaset so that each pod would connect to its respective persistent volume (perhaps using the matchLabels selector).
So I created three volumes by applying the following file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-pv-00
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  labels: 
    type: local
    service: mongo
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath: 
    path: "/mnt/mongodata/00"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-pv-01
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  labels: 
    type: local
    service: mongo
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath: 
    path: "/mnt/mongodata/01"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-pv-02
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  labels: 
    type: local
    service: mongo
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath: 
    path: "/mnt/mongodata/02"
```

and then I set up the replica set configuration file in the following way, but it still fails to connect the pods to the volumes:

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mongo-rs
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
spec:
  members: 3
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "4.4.0"
  persistent: true
  podSpec:
    persistence:
      single: 
        labelSelector: 
          matchLabels:
            type: local
            service: mongo
        storage: 5Gi
        storageClass: manual
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: data-volume
          spec:
            accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce", "ReadWriteMany" ]
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 5Gi
            selector:
              matchLabels:
                type: local
                service: mongo
            storageClassName: manual
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  users:
    - ...
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
```

I can't find any documentation online, except the [mongodb.com_v1_custom_volume_cr.yaml](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/config/samples/arbitrary_statefulset_configuration/mongodb.com_v1_custom_volume_cr.yaml), has anyone faced this problem before? How could I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could be interested into using local type of volumes. It works, like this:

**First**, you create a storage class for the local volumes. Something like the following:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Since it has `no-provisioner`, it will be usable only if you manually create local PVs. `WaitForFirstConsumer` instead, will prevent attaching a PV to a PVC of a Pod which cannot be scheduled on the host on which the PV is available.

Second, you create the local PVs. Similarly to how you created them in your example, something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /path/on/the/host
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - the-node-hostname-on-which-the-storage-is-located
```

Notice the definition, it tells the path on the host, the capacity.. and then it explains on which node of the cluster, such PV can be used (with the nodeAffinity). It also link them to the storage class we created early.. so that if someone (a claim template) requires storage with that class, it will now find this PV.

You can create 3 PVs, on 3 different nodes.. or 3 PVs on the same node at different paths, you can organize things as you desire.

**Third**, you can now use the `local-storage` class in claim template. The claim template could be something similar to this:

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: the-name-of-the-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "local-storage"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

And each Pod of the StatefulSet will try to be scheduled on a node with a `local-storage` PV available.

---

Remember that with local storages or, in general, with volumes that utilize host paths.. you may want to spread the various Pods of your app on different nodes, so that the app may resist the failure of a single node on its own.

---

In case you want to be able to decide which Pod links to which volume, the easiest way is to create one PV at a time, then wait for the Pod to `Bound` with it.. before creating the next one. It's not optimal but it's the easiest way.

Comment: you are the man! Thanks a lot for your help and your clear explanation!

Comment: @AndD After a lot of tests I found out that the relationship PV PVC is 1:1, so if you should create as many PV as you intend to create pods, and some extra for autoscaling. I wish I found this post earlier lol.

Comment: @Vincenzo PV - PVC relationships is not 1:1 mandatory. Certain PVs may support ReadMany or ReadWriteMany and be bound to multiple PVCs. Buy I agree that the majority of the time they are used 1:1

Comment: @AndD Oh so it is possible? I couldn't succeed in seething one up.. as a matter of facts that't exactly ho I wanted to set it up.. one disc with different routes..accessible by different claims.. would you you mind sharing how to achieve that? many many thanks

Comment: Setting that up requires some special read write many filesystem, check kubernetes explanation of the various pvc for access mode https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Comment: Sure! I got carried away with ReadWriteOnce and haven't really dung into it much more. I'm just starting with k8s and I'm setting up a mongodb 3 members replica set.. of course it's safer to have 3 different PVs  for disco failure etc etc but I'm exploring different settings.. After try to use ReplicaSet and failing to set ReplicaSet mode (mongo's replica set ) now I kinda got stuck with the MongoDBCommunity operator which makes it much more direct process..also scaling up and down members ( for future autoscaling setup) is a breeze .
Dough setting it up is not as straight as its seems..

Comment: I opened up a question here on SO at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154993/mongodb-community-operators-custom-resource-definitions-are-not-recognised-in-v/73186506#73186506 if you want to look at my journey wit it. Many thanks for your comments. Really appreciated it. Cheers .