# MongoDB Community operator's Custom Resource Definitions are not recognised in visual studio code

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I'm using docker desktop on an MacBook Air M1 and I just installed the MongoDBCommunity operator following the guide here https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/install-upgrade.md using the kubectl method.
Then I went to VS Code project and pasted a ReplicaSet following the guide here https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/deploy-configure.md in a .yaml file but I get an error:
`This apiVersion and/or kind does not reference a schema known by Cloud Code. Please ensure you are using a valid apiVersion and kind.`

if run the command `kubectl api-resources` I see it is installed

```
mongodbcommunity                  mdbc         mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1        true         MongoDBCommunity
```

As a test I commented out everything and re added one line at the time.`apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1` is accepted, but as soon as `kind: MongoDBCommunity` is added they both get underlined.

Install procedure used..

- Cloned the repo, and cd'ed into it.
  (Configure the Operator to watch other namespaces.)
- edited the manager file  /config/manager/manager.yaml

```
env:
        - name: WATCH_NAMESPACE
          value: "*"
          # valueFrom:
          #   fieldRef:
          #     fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

- edited the file in /deploy/clusterwide/cluster_role_binding.yaml

```
- kind: ServiceAccount
  namespace: default
  name: mongodb-kubernetes-operator
```

- applied it

```
kubectl apply -f deploy/clusterwide
```

- deploy a Role, RoleBinding and ServiceAccount in every namespace

```
kubectl apply -k config/rbac --namespace default
```

- Left untouched image and url for mongo in /config/manager/manager.yaml

```
- name: MONGODB_IMAGE
          value: mongo
        - name: MONGODB_REPO_URL
          value: docker.io
```

(Install)

- edited config/crd/bases/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    controller-gen.kubebuilder.io/version: v0.7.4  (this was a different version)
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mongodbcommunity.mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com
```

- applied it

```
kubectl apply -f config/crd/bases/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml
```

- Installed the necessary roles and role-bindings

```
kubectl apply -k config/rbac/ --namespace default
```

- Install the Operator

```
kubectl create -f config/manager/manager.yaml --namespace default
```

I went through the install process again and at each step verified the the step was applied correctly

```
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get crd/mongodbcommunity.mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com
NAME                                            CREATED AT
mongodbcommunity.mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com   2022-07-28T13:09:48Z
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get role mongodb-kubernetes-operator            
NAME                          CREATED AT
mongodb-kubernetes-operator   2022-07-28T13:10:28Z
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get role mongodb-kubernetes-operator --namespace default

NAME                          CREATED AT
mongodb-kubernetes-operator   2022-07-28T13:10:28Z
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get rolebinding mongodb-kubernetes-operator             
NAME                          ROLE                               AGE
mongodb-kubernetes-operator   Role/mongodb-kubernetes-operator   4h34m
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get rolebinding mongodb-kubernetes-operator --namespace default
NAME                          ROLE                               AGE
mongodb-kubernetes-operator   Role/mongodb-kubernetes-operator   4h34m
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get serviceaccount mongodb-kubernetes-operator         
NAME                          SECRETS   AGE
mongodb-kubernetes-operator   0         4h34m
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get serviceaccount mongodb-kubernetes-operator --namespace default
NAME                          SECRETS   AGE
mongodb-kubernetes-operator   0         4h34m
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get pods            
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-kubernetes-operator-7646658db4-8cnvn   1/1     Running   0          63m
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get pods --namespace default
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-kubernetes-operator-7646658db4-8cnvn   1/1     Running   0          63m
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get sts
No resources found in default namespace.
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl api-resources
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
bindings                                       v1                                     true         Binding
componentstatuses                 cs           v1                                     false        ComponentStatus
configmaps                        cm           v1                                     true         ConfigMap
endpoints                         ep           v1                                     true         Endpoints
events                            ev           v1                                     true         Event
limitranges                       limits       v1                                     true         LimitRange
namespaces                        ns           v1                                     false        Namespace
nodes                             no           v1                                     false        Node
persistentvolumeclaims            pvc          v1                                     true         PersistentVolumeClaim
persistentvolumes                 pv           v1                                     false        PersistentVolume
pods                              po           v1                                     true         Pod
podtemplates                                   v1                                     true         PodTemplate
replicationcontrollers            rc           v1                                     true         ReplicationController
resourcequotas                    quota        v1                                     true         ResourceQuota
secrets                                        v1                                     true         Secret
serviceaccounts                   sa           v1                                     true         ServiceAccount
services                          svc          v1                                     true         Service
mutatingwebhookconfigurations                  admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1        false        MutatingWebhookConfiguration
validatingwebhookconfigurations                admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1        false        ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
customresourcedefinitions         crd,crds     apiextensions.k8s.io/v1                false        CustomResourceDefinition
apiservices                                    apiregistration.k8s.io/v1              false        APIService
controllerrevisions                            apps/v1                                true         ControllerRevision
daemonsets                        ds           apps/v1                                true         DaemonSet
deployments                       deploy       apps/v1                                true         Deployment
replicasets                       rs           apps/v1                                true         ReplicaSet
statefulsets                      sts          apps/v1                                true         StatefulSet
tokenreviews                                   authentication.k8s.io/v1               false        TokenReview
localsubjectaccessreviews                      authorization.k8s.io/v1                true         LocalSubjectAccessReview
selfsubjectaccessreviews                       authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SelfSubjectAccessReview
selfsubjectrulesreviews                        authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SelfSubjectRulesReview
subjectaccessreviews                           authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SubjectAccessReview
horizontalpodautoscalers          hpa          autoscaling/v2                         true         HorizontalPodAutoscaler
cronjobs                          cj           batch/v1                               true         CronJob
jobs                                           batch/v1                               true         Job
certificatesigningrequests        csr          certificates.k8s.io/v1                 false        CertificateSigningRequest
leases                                         coordination.k8s.io/v1                 true         Lease
endpointslices                                 discovery.k8s.io/v1                    true         EndpointSlice
events                            ev           events.k8s.io/v1                       true         Event
flowschemas                                    flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta2   false        FlowSchema
prioritylevelconfigurations                    flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta2   false        PriorityLevelConfiguration
mongodbcommunity                  mdbc         mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1        true         MongoDBCommunity
ingressclasses                                 networking.k8s.io/v1                   false        IngressClass
ingresses                         ing          networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         Ingress
networkpolicies                   netpol       networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         NetworkPolicy
runtimeclasses                                 node.k8s.io/v1                         false        RuntimeClass
poddisruptionbudgets              pdb          policy/v1                              true         PodDisruptionBudget
podsecuritypolicies               psp          policy/v1beta1                         false        PodSecurityPolicy
clusterrolebindings                            rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRoleBinding
clusterroles                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRole
rolebindings                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         RoleBinding
roles                                          rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         Role
priorityclasses                   pc           scheduling.k8s.io/v1                   false        PriorityClass
csidrivers                                     storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        CSIDriver
csinodes                                       storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        CSINode
csistoragecapacities                           storage.k8s.io/v1                      true         CSIStorageCapacity
storageclasses                    sc           storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        StorageClass
volumeattachments                              storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        VolumeAttachment
```

it looks all good but still get the error..

Now there is one step

> For each namespace that you want the Operator to watch, run the following commands to deploy a Role, RoleBinding and ServiceAccount in that namespace:

```
kubectl apply -k config/rbac --namespace <my-namespace>
```

I did apply it only to `default` namespace but as these are my spacenames

```
default           Active   12d
ingress-nginx     Active   10d
kube-node-lease   Active   12d
kube-public       Active   12d
kube-system       Active   12d
```

should apply it to all of them??

What can I check to see if I did install it properly or not?

Thank you very much.
Cheers

Comment: I preferred using the helm chart to install the operator. It's better than changing the source, as your problem now will be that it's hard to upgrade given the differences in the source-tree. You can change the watched namespaces in the values you pass to helm. Once the operator is installed, I configure an instance of mongo using a crd (`mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1.MongoDBCommunity`) and a secret. The only problem I had with this was related to the domain name returned from the broker when trying to access the db externally, but this was easily solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer as the issue is not 100% solved..

So I could easily test settings and remove applied files
added all yaml files in the skaffold deploy: kubectl: manifests:

```
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      # # - ./infra/k8s/*
      
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/crd/bases/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/rbac/role_binding_database.yaml
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/rbac/role_binding.yaml
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/rbac/role_database.yaml
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/rbac/role.yaml
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/rbac/service_account_database.yaml
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/rbac/service_account.yaml
      - /Users/vincenzocalia/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/config/manager/manager.yaml
```

As first test I just added a `namespace: default` in `/config/rbac/role_binding_database.yaml`, `/config/rbac/role_binding.yaml`,
`/config/rbac/role_database.yaml`,
`/config/rbac/role.yaml`,
`/config/rbac/service_account_database.yaml`,
`/config/rbac/service_account.yaml` files.

No difference..Pod are still not been scheduled even if I add a `namespace: default` to the MongoDBCommunity ..

I found that I wrongly edited `config/crd/bases/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml` file  so I put back the controller-gen.kubebuilder.io/version: to correct `v0.4.1` value, dough it didn't solve my issue.  Desired Pod are still not been scheduled.

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    controller-gen.kubebuilder.io/version: v0.4.1 #v0.7.4  
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mongodbcommunity.mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com
```

I decided to try and edited back also the manager file /config/manager/manager.yaml to leave operator watching the the specified namespace instead of any as I set it initially

```
env:
        - name: WATCH_NAMESPACE
          # value: "*"
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

and BINGO! now pod get scheduled even without the `namespace: default` parameter in the MongoDBCommunity resource..not sure why they didn't with `value: "*"` but the do start now.

Still I get the `error: This apiVersion and/or kind does not reference a schema known by Cloud Code. Please ensure you are using a valid apiVersion and kind.` warning dough..

I'll update my answer as soon as I do solve the apiVersion/kind  issue..